# Моя учётная запись временно заблокирована. Что это значит?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Моя учётная запись [временно заблокирована](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) со следующими ограничениями:

- репутация учётной записи снижена до 1 балла;
- в профиле участника видно, что учётная запись временно заблокирована, и указан срок блокировки;
- владелец учётной записи не может голосовать, задавать вопросы, отвечать на них или публиковать комментарии.

Какие ещё ограничения предполагает временная блокировка? Например, могу ли я редактировать собственные сообщения или удалять их?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ограничения при блокировке учётной записи

- Репутация учётной записи снижается до 1 балла.
- В профиле участника появляется отметка о временной блокировке учётной записи с указанием причины и срока блокировки.
- Владелец учётной записи лишается возможности задавать вопросы, отвечать на них, комментировать публикации, использовать [привилегии](/help/privileges), принимать ответы или начинать конкурсы.
- Возможность переноса сообщений с других сайтов [запрещена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102293/274323) и заблокирована.

#### Возможности во время блокировки

- Сохраняется возможность получать знаки.

#### Изменения по истечении срока блокировки

- Заработанные баллы репутации будут восстановлены. После снятия блокировки количество баллов репутации может измениться, так как за это время другие участники могли проголосовать за или против ваших сообщений; возможно, какие-то сообщения были удалены или полученные голоса были признаны [недействительными](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/274323).
- Запись о блокировке и её причина сохраняется, но видна только ♦ модераторам.
- Ранее заблокированный участник [не имеет права](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274114/351781) баллотироваться на выборах модераторов в течение года после окончания блокировки.

#### Дополнительная информация

- Временная блокировка не связана с [фильтрацией сообщений по качеству](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). Это разные процессы. Возможны ситуации, когда, несмотря на снятие временной блокировки, вы не сможете задавать вопросы или отвечать на них. Это значит, что ваша учётная запись была заблокирована системой автоматически в связи с низким качеством ваших сообщений.