# Насколько гуманна инкрементальная блокировка участников

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, блокировка

Я бы хотел уточнить некоторые моменты касательно текущей практики блокировок участников от модсостава и администрации сайта и послушать мнение участников, насколько гуманной они считают текущую практику инкрементальной блокировки участников.

Итак, речь о "временных блокировках" – в простонародьи "баном". Я бы хотел сузить вопрос на основной сайт, а не на чат (насколько я вижу по текущей практики чаты как-то не в фокусе внимания у управляющей компании). Напоминаю, что временные блокировки – это НЕ "фильтрация сообщений по качеству" (за плохие посты), механизм другой.

- [Моя учётная запись временно заблокирована. Что это значит?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5493/213987)
- [Блокировка и её последствия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6703/213987)
- [Почему мы не храним отметки о блокировках в открытом доступе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7276/213987)

Если я правильно понимаю текущую практику, то любое повторное нарушение влечёт инкрементальное возрастание бана: неважно какое было нарушение в первый раз – но во второй раз срок блокировки будет в два раза больше:

> Система призывает модераторов следовать правилу увеличения срока
>   блокировки: 7 дней, 30 дней и один год. Выбранные сообществом
>   модераторы не могут блокировать участников более чем на один год.

Рассмотрим гипотетическую ситуацию с участником, который достаточно давно на сайте, внёс значительный вклад и на текущий момент обладает достаточно большой репутацией, скажем, 10к+.

В те времена, когда участник набрал только 2 - 3 к репутации (тот самый период, когда по статистике участники набирают основные баны) было два конфликта, которые привели к бану этого участника, первый – на неделю, а второй - уже на 30 дней, такие правила.

И вот прошло с тех пор два года, выводы были сделаны и урок усвоен: участник с тех пор стал вести себя более спокойно и успел ответить на большое множество вопросов.

Но хотя никто кроме модераторов не видит – информация о проведённых ранее нарушениях не делась, а осталась в карточке участника. И в случае если произойдёт какой-либо повтор инцидента, то бан автоматически будет выписан сразу на год.

Я правильно понимаю букву закона?

Если так, то я хотел бы спросить у участников – считают ли они данное правило гуманным по отношению к участникам?

Я слышал пояснения Николаса, мол инкремент – вещь полезная и нужная, она позволяет минимизировать затраты на администрирование блокировок. Есть такие люди, которые после бана придут и устроят ещё большую склоку – и если бантайм увеличивать инкрементально, то это сильно экономит усилия модераторов.

Моё личное мнение таково. Даже если это и полезно, то это негуманно. Особенно – по отношению к участникам, которые достаточно адекватны, чтобы по выходу из бана тут же не устраивать повторные скандалы. (Презумпция и всё такое)

Я слышал от весьма уважаемых мною модераторов, что прибегать к значительным банам модераторы не любят и чтобы смягчить положение стараются предварительно объявить предупреждение. Эдакий "выстрел в воздух", означающий, что следующий будет на поражение: считаем, что адекватный человек остановится и перестанет нарушать.

Однако мне кажется, что это костыль, полумера. Намного логичнее мне кажется, чтобы после полугода после бана отчёт срока начинался заново – с семи дней. Вероятно, сайт stackoverflow и не так дружелюбен – но можно сделать его гуманнее в некоторых аспектах. Конкретно этот аспект контролируется исключительно администрацией и ответственность за него никак не переложить на недружелюбных участников.

Как думаете?

Comment: Конечно, правильно начинать заново. Даже в уголовной практике через некоторое время после "на свободу с чистой совестью" сама судимость сниматся (т.е. статьи УПК в отношении рецидива не могут быть применены)

Comment: Да это вообще негуманно и это тянется со времён Jeff Atwood'а, благодаря которому была принята целая куча, мягко говоря, спорных решений, а очень правильные и популярные идеи отвергались. Очень жаль, что многие из них до сих пор не пересмотрены. В любом случае, мы здесь только сможем вас морально поддержать и небольшой шанс что-то изменить есть только на главной мете.

Comment: Есть и понятие рецидива

Answer (score 10):

Будучи модератором на [сайте «Русский язык»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), я хорошо знаком с механизмом назначения блокировок, поэтому попробую дать ответ на ваш вопрос.

> Если я правильно понимаю текущую практику, то любое повторное нарушение влечёт инкрементальное возрастание бана: **неважно какое было нарушение в первый раз** – но во второй раз срок блокировки будет в два раза больше

Нет, вы ошибаетесь. Длительность блокировки напрямую связана с серьезностью происшедшего. Так, если участник постоянно развязывает ненужные диалоги в комментариях, мы не будем блокировать его учетную запись на семь дней, а можем всего лишь выдать предупреждение и попросить не нарушать впредь правила. Допустим, это сообщение осталось без должного внимания; тогда модераторы вынуждены привлечь внимание нарушителя, используя более заметный инструмент — временную блокировку. Длительные дискуссии в комментариях, однако, трудно назвать *серьезным* нарушением, поэтому выдавать предусмотренные для более тяжелых проступков блокировки нельзя, а значит, одного дня ограничений будет достаточно. В случае если тот же участник продолжит наступать на те же самые грабли, длительность бана действительно будет с каждым разом возрастать.

Представим, что тот же пользователь сменил сферу своих интересов и начал промышлять толстым троллингом. Такое поведение влечет за собой уже *серьезное* нарушение, а следовательно, и серьезные последствия. Обычно за оскорбительное отношение к другим участникам предусмотрены такие наказания: первое нарушение — семь дней бана, второе — 30, а третье — 365. И то, что он по молодости любил разводить в комментариях антимонии, чаще всего никак не влияет на срок блокировки за оскорбления.

> Но хотя никто кроме модераторов не видит – информация о проведённых ранее нарушениях не делась, а осталась в карточке участника. И в случае если произойдёт какой-либо повтор инцидента, то **бан автоматически будет выписан сразу на год**.

Вы правильно заметили, что модераторам доступна история поведения участника. Думаю, что логично задаться вопросом: а зачем, собственно, она нужна? Ответ таков: чтобы принимать верные решения в случае возникновения новых проблем.

Если когда-то давно человек часто нарушал правила, но затем одумался и прекратил это делать, то, конечно, было бы странно сразу блокировать его на год, вспоминая проступки двухлетней давности. Снисхождение в таких ситуациях возможно, но не обязательно (если участник — хитрый тролль, просто выжидавший момент, то, безусловно, о послаблениях и речи быть не может).

Кажется, я ни про что не забыл, но если все-таки не упомянул что-то важное, обязательно укажите на это. В случае же каких-то ошибок, уверен, что коллеги меня поправят.

Кстати говоря, в [нормах поведения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/conduct), в частности, хорошо описаны обычные действия модераторов, когда они рассматривает жалобу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, встречались ли на практике исключительно упертые личности, возвращавшиеся после годового бана?

Comment: @avp встречались :) Приходится уделять особое внимание их активности по возвращении...

Comment: @avp, да вот недавно же (месяц-два назад) в главном чате же тема поднималась по поводу этого, в итоге, недавно "откинувшийся" ушел на следующий год

Answer (score 7):

В добавление а не противопоставление ответу Aer добавлю так же ответ с точки зрения прагматика.

Ситуация когда участник, внесший значительный вклад и обладающий большой репутацией, получает годичный бан требует внимательного анализа и поиска предпосылок, которые к ней привели. Вот почему.

Обычно в интернет сообществах правила поведения не многочисленны, не противоречивы, логичны. Существуют даже пользователи, никогда не читавшие правил и при этом никогда их не нарушающие. Маловероятно что человек, получивший два бана, никогда не читал правил или забыл их спустя несколько лет. Скорее всего, он нарушает осознанно (в знак протеста) или по какой-то объективной причине.

Такая ситуация может указывать на скрытые проблемы. Приведу для примера несколько.

1. Правила сообщества противоречивы, не логичны, слишком обширны, или часто меняются. Модераторы или пользователи могут трактовать их по разному.
2. Количество нарушителей слишком велико, модераторы утомлены этой проблемой, рассматривают нарушения менее внимательно и чаще принимают решения по букве закона а не по здравому смыслу.
3. Некий модератор недобросовестно исполняет свои обязанности, некорректно трактует правила, или злоупотребляет властью по личным мотивам.
4. Некий пользователь по личным мотивам или от смены мировоззрения сознательно нарушает правила с определенной целью или без нее, и намерен продолжать это делать.
5. итд.

Ни одна из явно перечисленных выше проблем не решается пересмотром механизма инкрементального бана. Скорее всего, проблемы, которые можно было бы перечислить после четвертого пункта не решаются тоже, но это не точно.

Пересмотр механизма инкрементного бана и его изменение в сторону улучшения сам по себе не является не желательным. Но явно требует уделения человеко-часов для обдумывания деталей, последствий, приведения в силу. Если проблемы как таковой нет, возможно не имеет смысла тратить время и силы на пересмотр механизма. А если проблема существует, тем более следует бросить силы и время на решение предпосылок проблемы, а не на бесполезный пересмотр механизма инкрементного бана.